# How do you configure Pacemaker to mount the DRBD data directory on the slave?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cluster, drbd, pacemaker

how do you get the Slave node of a DRBD pair to mount the data directory so data can be sync'd?

I went through the following guide: https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ClusterStack/Natty#Prepare_Partitions to get the 2-node cluster setup. I have the nodes connected but the data directory on the secondary node is never mounted so the data from node-1 is never replicated to node-2.

Pacemaker "should" be mounting the drive on the Node 2 with this command:

```
primitive res_fs ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/mnt/eoacluster" fstype="ext4" # Mounts the filesystem specifying the DRBD device and mount point.
```

Here is the output of drdb-overview:

Node 1:

```
0:eoa-ib  Connected Primary/Secondary UpToDate/UpToDate C r---- 
/mnt/eoacluster ext4 99G 188M 94G 1%
```

Node 2:

```
0:eoa-ib  Connected Secondary/Primary UpToDate/UpToDate C r----
```

Below is df -h

Node 1:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/DATA-root
                      96G  4.3G   87G   5% /
none                  496M  232K  496M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 501M  3.6M  497M   1% /dev/shm
none                  501M  104K  501M   1% /var/run
none                  501M  4.0K  501M   1% /var/lock
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1             228M   51M  165M  24% /boot
/dev/drbd0             99G  188M   94G   1% /mnt/eoacluster
```

Node 2:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/DATA-root
                       96G  3.0G   88G   4% /
none                  496M  232K  496M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 501M  3.2M  498M   1% /dev/shm
none                  501M  104K  501M   1% /var/run
none                  501M  4.0K  501M   1% /var/lock
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1             228M   51M  165M  24% /boot
```

/mnt/eoacluster directory does exist on Node 2.

What am I missing? Anyone have any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's perfect. Only one node can mount the DRDB. Your data is being replicated because status says: UpToDate/UpToDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this was a NOOB question. For those of you wondering, as it turns out DRBD does the sync behind the scenes and only mounts the disk on the active node. My output for drbd-overview is correct.